# XOR-Product Modulo Prime

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, computational-mathematics

Every natural number seems to map to a polynomial in binary field GF(2). For example, $11 = 1011_2 \mapsto x^3 + x + 1$, and $x^3 + x + 1 \mid_{x=2}$ gives 11. How naturally can I go between natural numbers modulo a prime like $10^9 + 7$ and their polynomials? Does it depend on if $10^9 + 7$ maps to an irreducible polynomial? (I don't know what the proper terminology is for this mapping.)

More specifically, let $\otimes$ be the XOR-product, computed by doing binary multiplication but XORing the intermediate results instead of adding. This corresponds to polynomial multiplication in the binary field. This comes from [Project Euler #813](https://projecteuler.net/problem=813)

$$
\begin{align*}
\phantom{\otimes 1111} 1011_2 \\
\otimes \phantom{1111} 1011_2 \\
\hline
\phantom{\otimes 1111} 1011_2 \\
\phantom{\otimes 111} 1011_2 \phantom{9} \\
\oplus \phantom{1} 1011_2  \phantom{999} \\
\hline
\phantom{\otimes 11} 1000101_2 \\
\end{align*}
$$

Can I compute $a \otimes b \equiv (a \% m) \otimes (b \% m) \pmod m$ like for standard multiplication? ($\%$ is the modulo operator in programming, for example $5 \% 3 = 2$.) I guess this is like asking $(f \times g)(2) \equiv (f(2) \% m) \times (g(2) \% m) \mod m$.

Example that suggests it's not true: $11 \otimes 11 = 69$, but $(11 \% 7) \otimes (11 \% 7) = 4 \otimes 4 = 16$, and $16 \%7 \neq 69\%7$.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. To multiply polynomials over $GF(p)$ you use the ordinary polynomial multiplication algorithm, with the coefficient arithmetic mod $p$.

Comment: @EthanBolker the last paragraph is clearer on what I am asking

Comment: It's not clear to me. Perhaps it is to others. You should [edit] the question to show us a worked out example mod $3$ of what you mean. You might even answer your own question by doing that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so what I understand is that I can work mod x^30 + x^29 + ..., whatever the polynomial corresponding to 10^9+7 is, and doing polynomial division is the same as if final integer result is modulo 10^9 + 7?  Does it matter if that polynomial is irreducible?

Comment: The reason I treat integers as polynomials is because the resulting numbers, like 11^(8^12 12^8) are too huge to fit into computer memory. I think the crux of the problem is using [binary exponentiation](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/binary-exp.html). Another idea I had was that 2^(5e8+3) equiv 1 mod 10^9+7 (multiplicative order), so maybe I only need to consider polynomials up to degree 5e8 + 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that the problem asks for you:

- to compute the power $P(x):=(x^3+x+1)^N$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ where $N=8^{12}\cdot12^8=2^{52}\cdot3^8$,
- then to think of $P(x)$ as a polynomial with integer coefficients, and calculate the remainder of $P(2)$ modulo the usual Project Euler prime $q=10^9+7$.

The way I would approach this is to:

1. Compute the power $$p(x)=(x^3+x+1)^{3^8}=\sum_{i=0}^{3^9}b_ix^i$$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$. Use square-and-multiply to do this. Now you have a list of the coefficients $b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_{19683}$.
2. Then use the trick that in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ squaring is additive to conclude that $$P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{3^9}b_ix^{2^{52}i}.$$
3. Then calculate the remainder of $\sum_{i=0}^{3^9}b_i2^{2^{52}i}$ modulo $q$ by whatever methodology you want. At this stage it is simply about calculating the remainder of a bunch of large numbers modulo $q$. The techniques have been covered e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619).

Observe that only step 1 uses XOR-powers. Step 2 is a trick sometimes called the *Freshman's dream* (in characteristic two). In step 3 no XORring is done, it is all usual integer arithmetic.

Of course, I may have misinterpreted what Project Euler wants you to do here. Anyway, there is still a non-trivial amount of programming to do to find that sequence of 19684 bits, and then use them in the last stage. Obvious shortcuts involving standard tricks of modular arithmetic apply.

Comment: squaring is additive / freshman's dream is the key I was missing I think. Otherwise doing xor-multiplication naively takes O(n^2) products like standard multiplication.

Comment: Multiplication without using FFT (which I don't know how to use anyway)

Comment: Freshman's dream also takes care of the squaring steps in square-and-multiply implementations of step 1.